# Make loaded svg invisible in snap.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I have loaded my svg image, but now I want to make it invisible. And I can't find a way to do it ...

```
var snapObj = Snap("#svgElement");
var group = snapObj.group();
var svgImage;

Snap.load("../img/image.svg", onImageLoaded);

function onImageLoaded(f) {
    svgImage = f;
    group.append(svgImage);
}
```

So now I need to know which attribute of svgImage I have to change the visibility of the image to false.

Comment: you could use the style attr to visibility hidden, or change the opacity to something very low I guess?

Comment: I already tried, but I always get the error message that the object doesn't have the method attr

Comment: The attr method worked, but you have to use it on the group, and not on the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me to solve the question, you can only use the attr method on a group and not on the loaded svg. So you need to add the loaded svg to a group.

```
var snapObj = Snap("#svgElement");
var group = snapObj.group();
var svgImage;

Snap.load("../img/image.svg", onImageLoaded);

function onImageLoaded(f) {
    // we add the svg to a group
    svgImage = snapObj.group().append(f);
    // we add the group with the svg to our other group
    group.append(svgImage);

    // and we can set the visibility to hidden 
    // and the image in group will be invisible
    svgImage.attr({
        visibility: "hidden"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way that worked for me:

```
var myPaper = Snap("#svgElement");
var theImage = myPaper.image("../img/image.svg");
theImage.attr({ display : "none" });
```

(adapted from [this post](http://www.alexnormand.com/blog/2014/03/09-show-hide-an-element-and-add-remove-classes-from-an-element-with-snapsvg/))

Comment: note: to show a hidden image set .attr({ display : "" })